# jQuery - If Else statement not working but works if separated into individual if statements

Tags: jquery, if-statement

The code below only works for the `if statement`, the subsequent `else if statements` do not fire. But if I separate all 3 into individual `if statements` everything works fine. How can I make them all play nice together?

**Not Working**

```
  if ( headingLength < 1 ) {
    // show error message
    $('.compose-wrap .message-heading .help-block').fadeIn();
  } else if ( messageLength < 1 ) {
    // show error message
    $('.compose-wrap .message-body .help-block').fadeIn();
  } else if ( formtagLength < 1 ) {
    // show error message
    $('.compose-wrap .choose-recipients .help-block').fadeIn();
  }
```

**Working**

```
  if ( headingLength < 1 ) {
    // show error message
    $('.compose-wrap .message-heading .help-block').fadeIn();
  }

  if ( messageLength < 1 ) {
    // show error message
    $('.compose-wrap .message-body .help-block').fadeIn();
  }

  if ( formtagLength < 1 ) {
    // show error message
    $('.compose-wrap .choose-recipients .help-block').fadeIn();
  }
```

Comment: You can do it by using the working part instead of the non-working part

Comment: Yes, yes I could but I want to know why the not working part is not working.

Comment: Because if you using the first part (not working) you only accessing the first **true** if statement condition, while if you have more than 1 true condition, then it will skip it and only run the code inside the first true condition

Comment: you might have conditons where `headingLength < 1` **and** `messageLength < 1` but you don't let the second one run.

Comment: Good comments thanks! Post it as an answer

Comment: You need to learn basic programming. `else` means that it only runs when the `if` condition failed.

Comment: @Barmar You need to learn basic social skills. This is a learning platform :)

Comment: Of course it is, but you're still expected to know the basics. This isn't a programming school, it's a place for programmers to get assistance from other programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if your running your `else if` when you dont want to.  If any one of the former conditions are solved the condition exits, this is expected behaviour.

**Answer**:
If you have something on the bottom thats not running which you expect to be running, then you probably don't want that part inside an else if.  If you do need it in the else if you need to carefully check your logic comparison operators.  e.g. the `>` `>=` `===` `==` `!=` `<=` `<` `&&` etc.. switch them around until you have what you want.

You can also combine them, e.g.

```
if ( headingLength < 1 ) {
    // show error message
    $('.compose-wrap .message-heading .help-block').fadeIn();
} else if ( (messageLength < 1) && headingLength >=1 ) {
    // show error message
    $('.compose-wrap .message-body .help-block').fadeIn();
} else {
    console.log('wasnt one of the above yet, rinse and repeat...');
}
```

Also, its best to end with a final else also, maybe with a console log, until you get it dialed in.

Answer (score 1):

you might have conditons where `headingLength < 1` and `messageLength < 1` but you don't let the second one run. *ELSE IF* should be used logically for Non-meeting conditions.