# Why is jquery and if statements not working together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

My code is supposed to hide several div's on load but for some reason when I type in the code that is supposed to bring up a div nothing happens. Please tell me why does the jQuery in my code not work with my `if` statements.

here is the java-script/jQuery and HTML (just in case)

```js
var code = $("#code");

function onstart(){
  $("#superfoods").hide();
  $("#fakemedia").hide();
  $("#dropbear").hide();
}

function checkcode(){
  if (code == "superfoods")
  { 
    $("#superfoods").show();
  }
  else if (code == "fakemedia")
  {
    $("#fakemedia").show();
  }
  else if (code == "dropbear")
  {
    $("#dropbear").show();
  }
  else {
    document.alert( code + "is not a valid imput.")
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="onstart()">
    <input id="code"><button onclick="checkcode()">search for level</button>
    <div id="superfoods">
        <a href="superfoods.html"><img src="super-food-400x400.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="fakemedia">
        <a href="fakemedia.html"><img src="fakemedia.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="dropbear">
        <a href="dropbear.html"><img src="drop-bearfgh.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `var code = $("#code").val();`

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579919/jquery-if-else-statement-not-working-but-works-if-separated-into-individual-if

Comment: Also you should set the value of code inside the checkcode function, otherwise the value of that variable isn't updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note:- In your code you are trying to compare object(`code`) with string values and hence your code didn't work.

So

```
var code = $("#code");// this is an object
```

Need to be:-

```
var code = $("#code").val();// this is a string now
```

***But since you are using jQuery, how about this solution:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("div").hide();// hide all divs
 
  var ids=[];//create an id's array
  
  $('div').each(function(){
    ids.push($(this).attr('id')); // get all div id's and push them to array
  });
  
  ids = ids.filter(Boolean); // remove empty+undefined values from array
  
  $('button').on('click',function(){//on click of button
  
    var code = $('#code').val();// get text-box value
    
    if ($.inArray( code, ids )>-1){ // if text-box value exist in array
    
      $("#"+code).show(); // show corresponding div
      
    }else {
    
      alert( code + "is not a valid imput."); // else alert
      
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <input id="code"><button>search for level</button><br/><br/>
    <div id="superfoods">
        <a href="superfoods.html"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTrfTcZ0t3zjzHrGzCiaoI9X94WB-fjDesGNNgjPI4W9bZZFHVf"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="fakemedia">
        <a href="fakemedia.html"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-nmxPn405_hKrvlT8tOghIpl8yQcMMJnuSYuExWgBW4N6TmUn"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="dropbear">
        <a href="dropbear.html"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRGqGpDhUX8weC_xIjO_COdt4F03dA58e5feBQw48VuZ6diJQXj"></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Note:- This code has ***advantage*** that it will work fine for ***increasing number of div's***. (just make sure id must be unique for each div's)

Answer (score 0):

1. `var code = $("#code");` 
   this statement returns an element not a string

use `var code = $("#code").val();` to return a string

2. `<input id="code">` will alway run `else` statement

set it a value

3. `document.alert` 
   javascript has not this function
   use only `alert`

You can also use `switch` statement like

```
function checkcode(){
    switch (code)
    {
        case "superfoods":
            $("#superfoods").show();
            break;
        case "fakemedia":
            $("#fakemedia").show();
            break;
        case "dropbear":
            $("#dropbear").show();
            break;
        default:
            alert( code + "is not a valid imput.");
    }
}
```